# AssociationTypeMismatch with Expected Type on Nested Model Forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, nested-forms

I'm getting this exception when doing a nested model form:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RecipesController#update 
  Ingredient(#35624480) expected, got Ingredient(#34767560)
```

The models involved are Recipe and Ingredient. Recipe has_many and accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, which belongs_to :recipe.

I get this exception when attempting to _destroy (=1) one of the preexisting Ingredients on a nested Ingredient form for the Recipe Edit/Update.

This makes very little sense, mostly because the association types are as expected (by the exception's own admission).

What makes even less sense is that it [works just fine in a functional test](http://gist.github.com/412413).

Also, it sometimes works if I re-post the form (via a browser refresh on Update). It also will work if I restart the (development) webserver.

Any ideas what might be causing this, or what I should be looking for?

Comment: Have you compared the log entries for the first (failing) and second (successful) updates?

Comment: Nope, but that's a good idea. Thanks.

Comment: The logs were identical up until the deletion; the failed log has the exception, the successful one has the delete SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this usually means "rails failed to reload successfully once"
in your environment/xxx files you can change it to not reload, or allow it to reload.

Comment: Hi @rogerdpack; are you referring to the config.cache_classes property?

Comment: It definitely looks like a class-loading issue; I switched config.cache_classes to true in development and the problem disappeared.

Comment: Looks like you fixed it.  For me this meant that my plugins weren't reloading right or some odd...

Answer (score -1):

This can sometimes be fixed by adding correct require's, start where the class is used in **your** code